# Spring for Android - Custom Rest Template

Tags: android, spring, jackson

I am using Spring for Android and pulling JSON data by doing:

**CourseActivity.java**

```
private void getCourses()
{
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
  String url = "http://192.168.1.74:3000/andy/courses.json";
  Course[] coursesArray = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Course[].class);

  ...
}
```

**Course.java**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Course implements Parcelable, DBObject
{
    @JsonProperty
    private String number = null;
    @JsonProperty
    private String title = null;
    @JsonProperty
    private int school_id = -1;
    @JsonProperty
    private String department = null;

    ...
}
```

The JSON call returns this type of data:

```
[{"id":1,"number":"CE-490","title":"Senior Design","school_id":1,"department":"Computer Engineering"},{"id":2,"number":"CE-491","title":"Introduction to Mobile App Development","school_id":1,"department":"Computer Engineering"}]
```

Now you can see that the JSON data keys map directly to my Course attribute names.

What if I wanted to have different names? Specifically, if my JSON returns a key such as "notify_on_follow", how can I use Spring for Android to map that to "notifyOnFollow" without underscores? Or maybe changing "active" to "isActive"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find the docs, but I'm pretty sure this will work:

```
@JsonProperty("notify_on_follow")
private SomeType notifyOnFollow;
```

Comment: Thanks @Jim, I'll give it a shot soon. Appreciate it.